# import store items from Magento to Craft Commerce

Tags: import

is there a plugin or script to import products, accounts, categories from Magento to Craft Commerce?
Or is this something to be written from scratch with FeedMe?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a plugin that does this. However, I would like to point you to a talk by James Greig that happened last Friday, in which he explains a number of possible ways to migrate content from X to Craft. He too uses FeedMe to do the import part, but has a few approaches to exporting the content on the other side:

https://www.greig.cc/dotall2018

Comment: Looking at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40756/magento-product-feed-in-xml you could write something custom to convert your Magento products to XML for Feed Me (Pro)